# HP 3700 and a Mac Pro laptop. It stopped printing color

Tags: mac, printer, colors

I have a HP 3700 and a Mac Pro laptop(running on Ventura 13.2). The printer stopped printing color, so I replace the ink. Still no reds blues - everything is pink or faded blank. I thought it was the printer so purchased a new one - Envy Inspire 7255E.  Set it all up using the HP Smart app and same issue, no color??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The print heads built into inkjet ink cartridges can get clogged. Don't assume they're working fine just because they're new; they could have leaked a tiny bit of ink and gotten clogged in shipping or on the shelf in the warehouse. Skip the Mac and go straight to the printers' front panel buttons/screens, and run some test prints / diagnostics, and maybe print head cleaning cycles if necessary. Prove that your printers can successfully print all four ink colors first. Please edit your Question to include details on what else (besides buying a second printer) you've already tried and ruled out.

Comment: Once you've printed a test sheet form the printer, try printing a page of black text; then some solid colour objects; then a photo. check over all the options in the print menu. Ventura has changed the print dialog somewhat - click on the circle-i info buttons for more options.